Exclude a Flask view from session creation?
I have a Flask app that uses Flask-Session to store session data in Redis between a few containers running as a Kubernetes Deployment. That's all working fine, but I recently started looking closer at the Redis database and noticed it has way more keys than I expected, and it seems that the readiness and metrics endpoints of my app (which are polled quite frequently) are creating a new session each time.
Is there a way to exclude specific Flask views from the session creation process? e.g. something like a @flask.nosession decorator for the view would be ideal, or force only those sessions to a much shorter life?


Are you using permanent sessions? Does your session expire?

I am and they do (after a day), but between prometheus and readiness probes, that's 100K unnecessary sessions in redis (over a few app replicas)!

Are you using this approach to store session data in redis session["key"] = "value"?

Not in the views that provide metrics and readiness, but yes in the actual application for logged-in users.

The simplest approach is to just have the cookies expire every 48 hours or so. Though since this doesn't answer your question, I'll make a more in-depth answer.
From my understanding, you want certain pages to not create a new session. Since there is no built in decorator that provides this functionality, you can make one yourself (or myself haha).
Imports
from functools import wraps
from flask import session

Custom Decorator
def nosession_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        session.permanent = False
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function

Routes
# Example usage:
@app.route('/no-session')
@nosession_required
def no_session_view():
    return 'No session created'

@app.route('/normal-session')
def normal_session_view():
    return 'Usual behavior (created session)'


Here's another approach, though it doesn't use decorators, it can be an alternative should another issue arise.
Imports
It only requires flask.
from flask import Flask, session

Modifying session creation
You can modify what happens before a session is created.
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if 'exclude_session' in session:
        session.permanent = False  # Set session to non-permanent
    else:
        session.permanent = True   # Set session to permanent (default behavior)

Routes
Finally, you can simply use these in your routes.
# Example view with excluded session creation
@app.route('/no-session')
def no_session_view():
    session['exclude_session'] = True  # Mark this view to exclude session creation
    return 'No session was created.'

# Example view with default session behavior
@app.route('/normal-session')
def normal_session_view():
    return 'Session created.'


If you set session.permanent in the "before_request" event, and then session['exclude_session'] IN the request, isn't it too late? Does setting permanent=False after a session is created actually delete it?
